# spaCy Documentation for [ orth , pos , tag, lema and text ]

Tags: python, nlp, cython, spacy

I am new to spaCy. I added this post for documentation and make it simple for new starters as me.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'KEEP CALM because TOGETHER We Rock !')
for word in doc:
    print(word.text, word.lemma, word.lemma_, word.tag, word.tag_, word.pos, word.pos_)
    print(word.orth_)
```

I am looking to understand what the meaning of orth, lemma, tag and pos ? This code print out the values also what the different between `print(word)` vs `print(word.orth_)`

Comment: Here it explains ORTH and LOWER...

https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ## What the meaning of orth, lemma, tag and pos ?

See https://spacy.io/docs/usage/pos-tagging#pos-schemes

> ## What the different between print(word) vs print(word.orth_)

**In super short:**

`word.orth_` and `word.text` are the same. The fact that the cython property ends with an underscore, it's usually a variable that the developers didn't really want to expose to the user.

**In short:**

When you access the `word.orth_` property at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L537, it tries to access the index of where all the vocabulary of words are kept:

```
property orth_:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.vocab.strings[self.c.lex.orth]
```

(For details, see **`In long`** below for explanation of `self.c.lex.orth`)

And `word.text` returns the string representation of the word which merely wraps around the `orth_` property, see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L128

```
property text:
    def __get__(self):
        return self.orth_
```

And when you're printing `print(word)`, it calls the `__repr__` dunder function that returns the `word.__unicode__` or `word.__byte__` which points back to the `word.text` variable, see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L55

```
cdef class Token:
    """
    An individual token --- i.e. a word, punctuation symbol, whitespace, etc.
    """
    def __cinit__(self, Vocab vocab, Doc doc, int offset):
        self.vocab = vocab
        self.doc = doc
        self.c = &self.doc.c[offset]
        self.i = offset

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.doc, self.i))

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Number of unicode characters in token.text.
        """
        return self.c.lex.length

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text

    def __bytes__(self):
        return self.text.encode('utf8')

    def __str__(self):
        if is_config(python3=True):
            return self.__unicode__()
        return self.__bytes__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

---

**In long:**

Let's try to walk through this step by step:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> doc = nlp(u'This is a foo bar sentence.')
>>> type(doc)
<type 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>
```

After the sentence is passed into the `nlp()` function, it produces a [`spacy.tokens.doc.Doc`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/9003fd25e5e966bd8d1b67a18f3ebd6010d6f718/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx#L66) object, from the docs:

```
cdef class Doc:
    """
    A sequence of `Token` objects. Access sentences and named entities,
    export annotations to numpy arrays, losslessly serialize to compressed
    binary strings.
    Aside: Internals
        The `Doc` object holds an array of `TokenC` structs.
        The Python-level `Token` and `Span` objects are views of this
        array, i.e. they don't own the data themselves.
    Code: Construction 1
        doc = nlp.tokenizer(u'Some text')
    Code: Construction 2
        doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, orths_and_spaces=[(u'Some', True), (u'text', True)])
    """
```

So the `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` object is a sequence of [`spacy.tokens.token.Token`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L25) object. Within the `Token` object, we see a wave of cython `property` enumerated, e.g. at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L162

```
property orth:
    def __get__(self):
        return self.c.lex.orth
```

Tracing it back, we see that `self.c = &self.doc.c[offset]`:

```
cdef class Token:
    """
    An individual token --- i.e. a word, punctuation symbol, whitespace, etc.
    """
    def __cinit__(self, Vocab vocab, Doc doc, int offset):
        self.vocab = vocab
        self.doc = doc
        self.c = &self.doc.c[offset]
        self.i = offset
```

Without thorough documentation, we don't really know what `self.c` means but from the looks of it it's accessing one of the tokens within the `&self.doc` reference pointing to the `Doc doc` that was passed into the `__cinit__` function. So most probably, it's a short cut to access the tokens

Looking at the `Doc.c`:

```
cdef class Doc:
    def __init__(self, Vocab vocab, words=None, spaces=None, orths_and_spaces=None):
        self.vocab = vocab
        size = 20
        self.mem = Pool()
        # Guarantee self.lex[i-x], for any i >= 0 and x < padding is in bounds
        # However, we need to remember the true starting places, so that we can
        # realloc.
        data_start = <TokenC*>self.mem.alloc(size + (PADDING*2), sizeof(TokenC))
        cdef int i
        for i in range(size + (PADDING*2)):
            data_start[i].lex = &EMPTY_LEXEME
            data_start[i].l_edge = i
            data_start[i].r_edge = i
        self.c = data_start + PADDING
```

Now we see that the `Doc.c` is referring to a cython pointer array `data_start` that allocates the memory on to store the `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` object (please correct me if I get the explanation `<TokenC*>` wrong).

So going back to `self.c = &self.doc.c[offset]`, it's basically trying to access the memory point where the array is stored and more specifically accessing the "offset-th" item in the array.

That's what `spacy.tokens.token.Token` is.

---

Going back to the `property`:

```
property orth:
    def __get__(self):
        return self.c.lex.orth
```

We see that the `self.c.lex` is accessing the [`data_start[i].lex` from `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx#L110) and `self.c.lex.orth` is simply an integer that indicates the index of the occurrence of the word that is kept in the `spacy.tokens.doc.Doc` internal vocabulary.

Thus, we see the `property orth_` tries to access the `self.vocab.strings` with te index from `self.c.lex.orth` https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/develop/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L162

```
property orth_:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.vocab.strings[self.c.lex.orth]
```

Comment: """In super short:

... The fact that the cython property ends with an underscore, it's usually a variable that the developers didn't really want to expose to the user.""""  To not expose a var, the underscore is used at the beginning, not at the end. Spacy normally uses the underscore at the end for the unicode version of the attribute

Answer (score 2):

1) When you print `word`, you basically print [`Token`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/9003fd25e5e966bd8d1b67a18f3ebd6010d6f718/spacy/tokens/token.pyx) class from spacy which is set to print out string from the class. You can see more [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/9003fd25e5e966bd8d1b67a18f3ebd6010d6f718/spacy/tokens/token.pyx#L57-L63). So it's different from printing out `word.orth_` or `word.text` where these will print out string directly.

2) I'm not sure about `word.orth_`, seems like it is `word.text` for most cases. For `word.lemma_`, it's the lemmatize of the given word e.g. `is`, `am`, `are` will map to `be` in `word.lemma_`.